# Get default gateway using Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

Does anyone know how to get the default gateway in a Delphi 2010 app? I have found some windows functions like `GetAdaptersAddresses`, but I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*On Windows XP and later Use the GetAdaptersAddresses instead of GetAdaptersInfo.*

There is a set of functions implementing **IP Helper APIs**. see the delphi web page at [Magenta Systems](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magiphlp.asp)

Edit:
 from [Remok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137071/remko) comment :
GetAdaptersInfo returns **ERROR_NO_DATA**  if there is ONLY an IPv6 address configured. That's why MSDN recommends using GetAdapterAddresses.

Comment: I'm curious. Why is GetAdaptersAddresses to be preferred to  GetAdaptersInfo?

Comment: @David Heffernan: just a guess but maybe GetAdaptersAddressess supports IPv6?

Comment: @Najem D'oh! I should have found that myself! I hate it when they tell you what to do, but don't say why.

Comment: @David then you have to guess, I think Remko found the way

Comment: GetAdaptersInfo returns ERROR_NO_DATA if there is ONLY an IPv6 address configured. That's why MSDN recommends using GetAdapterAddresses.

Answer (score 0):

You call [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) contains a comprehensive example of how to call it.

Comment: IpHlpApi headers are already translated to Delphi in the Jedi ApiLib (JwaIpHlp.pas) if you need them.